# InvalidAuthenticationToken when trying to invoke Microsoft Graph client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm following a sample provided at the Microsoft Graph [repository on github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/docs/overview.md).  In it, it describes using the DelegateAuthenticationProvider which needs an access token.
Marc LaFleur's [primer on auth flow](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) specified a way to get the access token which I combined with [guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service/) on making service-service authentication work.

Even though I receive what **appears to be a valid access token**, when I issue the command via the graph client, I get a ServiceException from Microsoft Graph stating,

"{
    Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
    Message: Access token validation failure.
    Inner error
}"

I haven't seen any other inner error.

What am I doing incorrectly?

This is the code I've come up:

```
var clientId = "[app-guid]";
var clientSecret = "[secret-from-app-dashboard]";
var resource = "[app-guid]";
var baseUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
var loginUrl = "/[tenant guid]/oauth2/token";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", resource)
    });
    var result = client.PostAsync(loginUrl, content).Result;
    string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var json = JObject.Parse(resultContent);

    accessToken = (string)json["access_token"];

} 
var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
(requestMessage) =>
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = header;


    return Task.FromResult(0);
}));
try
{
    var users = await graphserviceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
    var user = users.First();
}
catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException servex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(servex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your resource to point to your website, but it should point to the external web resource you wish to access. Try this:

```
var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but  now I get this in my exception, "The identity of the calling application could not be established." For the accessToken returned, it seems to be OK, as it contains the name of the application being authenticated.

Comment: I was able to repro that issue in Postman but not in an application registered under the correct URL. I would double check your registration information, especially the URLs you registered. Did you register in the apps.dev.microsoft.com portal or with Azure AD?

I would also make sure your permissions are set correctly. At least Microsoft Graph and Windows Azure Service Management should be set up.